# configuration failed for package ‘units’ on Termius in Windows 10

Tags: r, linux, centos, install.packages, termius

I have a problem installing R package "units" on Termius. The linux distro and kernel version are CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core). When "units" was installed, it reported the following error message:[image]

I am using Windows 10 and have to use Termius to run R. Is there a way to resolve this issue in this case?

Comment: CentOS uses RPM and the error message points to `udunits2-devel`, usually installed with `rpm` or `yum` command line tools, try `yum install udunits2-devel`

Comment: Windows 10 for this problem is irrelevant. You can just focus on the error message in the environment (Termius/CentOS).

Comment: Hi thanks guys! I resolved this. We should load the module udunits into the environment and then it worked.